# SQLite PDO bindings do not work

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, pdo, prepared-statement

I have a little PHP script which just needs to get all the rows from a table in a SQLite database. 
The name of the table is always something like `174597131028398082-199534472775860224`.

This name is composed from two variables (`sid` and `cid`) which are defined through the parameters of a GET request. The problem is that instead of returning all the rows (which I would display later in the script), I get this error : `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: :sid-:cid`.

It seems like PHP does not replace `:sid` and `:cid` with the correct values. I've seen [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039986/sqlite-pdo-bindings-not-working) about a similar problem, but I still can't get it working.

Here's my code :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `:sid-:cid`;";

$queryparams = array(
    ':sid' => $_GET['sid'],
    ':cid' => $_GET['cid']
);

try {
  $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
  $result = $stmt->execute($queryparams);
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
  die($ex->getMessage());
}
```

Also, here is how I connect to the database :

```
try {
  $db = new PDO("sqlite:scores.db");
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
  die($ex->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Table and Column names cannot be replaced by parameters in PDO.

Comment: Oww. So there's no way to do what I want? :x

Comment: @Saty strange you can't do that.  I don't really know php, but is there a difference between a string passed as an argument and a string built from variables?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter

Comment: Whitelist and interpolate those values instead. Binding them won't work in any database. Btw, it also indicates a slight database misdesign. There's little reason to have multiple tables with the same structure. Instead include them as primary columns in a compound table.

Comment: Well at least now I know. Thanks! I'll try what you suggested.